# How can I reference a third party defined type/resource using puppet's ruby dsl?

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to use a third party resource that's included via ***metadata.json***.  This resource works fine in regular pp manifests, but if I use an rb manifest I get ***nomethoderror***.

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Puppet::Parser::Compiler failed with error NoMethodError: undefined method `network_routes' for #<Puppet::DSL::ResourceAPI:0x7350c31>
```

Working pp:

```
network_routes { '10.10.1.1': ... }
```

Not working rb:

```
network_routes('10.10.1.1', '...')
```

Comment: Show what you are trying to do as it is very unclear from your question.

Comment: Trying to use a third party resource called network_routes inside a Ruby DSL manifest.